# How to clear/delete Google Cloud Messaging Queue?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Situation is that I sent a notification from my server to 1 million users. Request is in queue at GCM. After triggering the notification from server I found that notification is not correct and it should not be sent. I want to stop it. At that point of time how I can clear/delete GCM queue?

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Is it a [collapsible message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages)? If not, I don't think there is anything that the community can do here. I suggest to contact GCM support by filling out [this form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support), if you are using GCM, or contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) if you're using FCM. Cheers!