# Withdraw FCM notification PHP

Tags: php, cordova, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

After sending a FCM notification using PHP a multicast id has been received.
is there any way withdrawing the sent notification using this multicast id?

For instance:
When whatsapp web is open on my pc, the whatsapp notification will be gone from my home screen on my phone after reading it on my pc.

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$notification= array(
    'body' => $message,
    'priority' => 10,
    'sound' => "default"
);

$fields = array(
    'to' => $targets,
    'notification' => $notification,
    'sound' => "default",
    'priority' => 10
);

$headers = array (
    'Authorization: key='.$gcmKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

This is how i 'send' the notification.

My app is being build using phonegap

Comment: I believe you need to send another push and cancel the notification at the app side with cancel method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)

Comment: Can't be done server side? and i'm using phonegap by the way ;)

Comment: Kinda [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41500042/4625829)? Anyways, AFAIK, there isn't any ways to withdraw the message that was successfully sent to the FCM server. You can replace it if it is a collapsible message though. Cheers!

Comment: This is irrelevant if you are using phonegap or not.